# Optimal online scheduling algorithm trying all combinations

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduling, job-scheduling

I have a thesis about online scheduling. Every task j has a weight Wj and a completion time Cj ( a time when it's complete not a duration ). The objective of the study is to study how close Sum(WjCj) of my algorithm comes close to the optimal algorithm. I'm doing my tests with 7 tasks as that's the maximum a brute force algorithm can go.

I'm trying to write an algorithm that tries all permutations and finds the one with least Sum(WjCj) as that's the objective of my bachelor thesis. This is only to compare my algorithm with it. Do you think that it is correct ?

```
    def brute_force_algorithm(self):
        sorted_tasks = sorted(self.tasks, key=lambda k: k['arrival_time'])
        all_permutations = list(itertools.permutations(sorted_tasks))
        min_sum_WjCj = float('inf')
        best_sequence = None
        for perm in all_permutations:
            for j in range(0,len(perm)):
                for i in range(j, len(perm)):
                    machine1_tasks = perm[:i]  # Tasks from the start to i are assigned to machine1
                    machine2_tasks = perm[i:]  # Remaining tasks are assigned to machine2
                    sum_WjCj = self.calculate_WjCj(list(machine1_tasks)) + self.calculate_WjCj(list(machine2_tasks))
                    if sum_WjCj < min_sum_WjCj:
                        min_sum_WjCj = sum_WjCj
                        best_sequence = (list(machine1_tasks), list(machine2_tasks))

        return best_sequence, min_sum_WjCj
```

```
[
      [  {"task_id": "Task_1", "processing_time": 2, "weight": 10, "arrival_time": 0},
        {"task_id": "Task_2", "processing_time": 2, "weight": 100, "arrival_time": 0},
        {"task_id": "Task_3", "processing_time": 2, "weight": 1000, "arrival_time": 0},
        {"task_id": "Task_4", "processing_time": 2, "weight": 10000, "arrival_time": 0},
        {"task_id": "Task_5", "processing_time": 2, "weight": 100000, "arrival_time": 0},
        {"task_id": "Task_6", "processing_time": 2, "weight": 1000000, "arrival_time": 0},
        {"task_id": "Task_7", "processing_time": 2, "weight": 10000000, "arrival_time": 0}
    ],
    [
        {"task_id": "Task_1", "processing_time": 2000, "weight": 1, "arrival_time": 0},
        {"task_id": "Task_2", "processing_time": 2000, "weight": 1, "arrival_time": 0},
        {"task_id": "Task_3", "processing_time": 2, "weight": 100000000, "arrival_time": 1}
    ],
    [
        {"task_id": "Task_1", "processing_time": 2000, "weight": 1, "arrival_time": 0},
        {"task_id": "Task_2", "processing_time": 2000, "weight": 1, "arrival_time": 0},
        {"task_id": "Task_3", "processing_time": 2, "weight": 100000000, "arrival_time": 1},
        {"task_id": "Task_4", "processing_time": 2, "weight": 100000000, "arrival_time": 1},
        {"task_id": "Task_5", "processing_time": 2, "weight": 100000000, "arrival_time": 1},
        {"task_id": "Task_6", "processing_time": 2, "weight": 100000000, "arrival_time": 1},
        {"task_id": "Task_7", "processing_time": 2, "weight": 100000000, "arrival_time": 1}
    ],
    [
        {"task_id": "Task_1", "processing_time": 1000, "weight": 1, "arrival_time": 0},
        {"task_id": "Task_2", "processing_time": 1000, "weight": 1, "arrival_time": 0},
        {"task_id": "Task_3", "processing_time": 10, "weight": 1, "arrival_time": 0},
        {"task_id": "Task_4", "processing_time": 10, "weight": 10000000000, "arrival_time": 1}
    ],
    [
        {"task_id": "Task_1", "processing_time": 20000, "weight": 1000000000, "arrival_time": 0},
        {"task_id": "Task_2", "processing_time": 20000, "weight": 1000000000, "arrival_time": 0},
        {"task_id": "Task_3", "processing_time": 2, "weight": 1, "arrival_time": 1}
    ]

    ]
```

I tried to write the optimal brute force Algorithm and I was expecting the best outcome